# GCC SSE Handwritten vs. Generated

Tags: c++, gcc, sse, simd

I am messing around with SIMD optimization and wrote a 3 very simple vector classes with addition implemented in 2 different ways, one handwritten component wise and one using _mm_add_ps https://godbolt.org/z/fPAERV.
Interestingly GCC was not able ( or I didn't tell it properly x) ) to implement the addition for vector2 using SSE, only after explicity adding a fourth float to the vector ( like in vector3 ) gcc generates the addition using SEE instructions even though I aligned the vector on a 16 byte boundary. Can anyone tell me why?

```
#include <xmmintrin.h>

struct alignas(16) vector final {
  union {
    struct {
      float x, y, z;
    };
    float axes[3];
    __m128 v;
  };

  vector(float x, float y, float z) noexcept : x(x), y(y), z(z) {};
  vector(__m128 v) noexcept : v(v){};
};

vector operator+(const vector& v0, const vector& v1) noexcept {
  return {_mm_add_ps(v0.v, v1.v)};
}

struct alignas(16) vector2 final {
  union {
    struct {
      float x, y, z;
    };
    float axes[3];
    __m128 v;
  };

  vector2(float x, float y, float z) noexcept : x(x), y(y), z(z) {};
  vector2(__m128 v) noexcept : v(v){};
};

vector2 operator+(const vector2& v0, const vector2& v1) noexcept {
  return {v0.x + v1.x, v0.y + v1.y, v0.z + v1.z};
}

struct alignas(16) vector3 final {
  union {
    struct {
      float x, y, z, w;
    };
    float axes[4];
    __m128 v;
  };

  vector3(float x, float y, float z, float w) noexcept : x(x), y(y), z(z), w(w) {};
  vector3(__m128 v) noexcept : v(v){};
};

vector3 operator+(const vector3& v0, const vector3& v1) noexcept {
  return {v0.x + v1.x, v0.y + v1.y, v0.z + v1.z, v0.w + v1.w};
}
```

generated assembly using gcc9.2 with -std=c++17 -O3 -Wall -Wextra

```
operator+(vector const&, vector const&):
        movaps  xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rsi]
        addps   xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rdi]
        movdqa  xmm0, xmm1
        movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rsp-24], xmm1
        movq    xmm1, QWORD PTR [rsp-16]
        ret
operator+(vector2 const&, vector2 const&):
        movss   xmm1, DWORD PTR [rdi+4]
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [rdi+8]
        addss   xmm1, DWORD PTR [rsi+4]
        addss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [rsi+8]
        movss   xmm2, DWORD PTR [rdi]
        addss   xmm2, DWORD PTR [rsi]
        movss   DWORD PTR [rsp-20], xmm1
        movss   DWORD PTR [rsp-16], xmm0
        movq    xmm1, QWORD PTR [rsp-16]
        movss   DWORD PTR [rsp-24], xmm2
        movq    xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsp-24]
        ret
operator+(vector3 const&, vector3 const&):
        movaps  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rdi]
        addps   xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rsi]
        movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rsp-40], xmm0
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsp-32]
        movq    xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsp-40]
        movq    xmm1, rax
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp-16], rax
        ret
```

Comment: i added the code with permalink to godbolt?

Comment: Please edit your code into the question.  Questions should be self contained and links should be for reference only.

Comment: Did you try with `-ffast-math`, or at least `-fno-trapping-math`?  Garbage in the high element could raise an FP exception if unmasked, so the default `-ftrapping-math` might be blocking optimization for that reason.  But in general compilers really don't like doing more than you tell them, even when it leads to missed optimizations like doing all 3 separately.

Comment: same output with both of those flags

Comment: Be aware that using `union` for type punning is undefined behavior in C++ (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373203/accessing-inactive-union-member-and-undefined-behavior) -- it may very well work fine on your compiler, but could break anytime!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"inventing writes" is usually disallowed, and can create nasty compiler bugs.  (Because of thread safety, e.g. stepping on writes from another thread).

Even though it's part of a union object, GCC internals probably treat that last element as separate and aren't willing to write it with "garbage".  So yes, this is a missed optimization that you'll have to work around manually.

---

In general SIMD vectors are not well suited to holding 3D geometry vectors.  Ideally you can structure your data so you can have a `__m128 x` of four `x` coordinates, and another `__m128 y` of four `y` coordinates, etc.  Then you can do 4 vector additions in 3 `addps` instructions.  Even better, doing 4 vector lengths   or other operations that use x, y, and z from the same vector together doesn't involve any shuffling.

See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info for links, especially [Slides: SIMD at Insomniac Games (GDC 2015)](https://deplinenoise.wordpress.com/2015/03/06/slides-simd-at-insomniac-games-gdc-2015/) which goes into more detail about using SIMD efficiently, among other things.

But sure, if you've already done that for the cases where you can lay out your data differently, there might still be other cases where you only have a couple individual vectors and need "float3" layouts, and can still use SIMD to speed that up some, too.